# Visual Studio 2015 Compiler Warning (Windows 10 Insider Build 14342)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ide, windows-10

since I have updated my Maschine to Windows 10 Insider slow ring Build 14342 I'm getting some warning while compiling my project.

```
Verarbeite COM-Verweis "" aus Pfad "C:\Windows\System32\stdole2.tlb". Der Typbibliothekimporter konnte die Signatur für den Member "DISPPARAMS.rgvarg" nicht konvertieren.  

Verarbeite COM-Verweis "" aus Pfad "C:\Windows\System32\stdole2.tlb". Der Typbibliothekimporter konnte die Signatur für den Member "DISPPARAMS.rgdispidNamedArgs" nicht konvertieren.
```

Translation:

```
Processing COM reference "" from path "C:\Windows\System32\stdole2.tlb". The type library importer could not convert the signature for the member "DISPPARAMS.rgvarg".

Processing COM reference "" from path "C:\Windows\System32\stdole2.tlb". The type library importer could not convert the signature for the member "DISPPARAMS.rgdispidNamedArgs".
```

Does anyone has an idea how to fix that error?

I already tried repairing the visual stuio 2015 and visual c++ redistributable software packages.

Comment: update to Build 14366 (fast Ring) and look if it works here

Comment: Do you have 14366 and can you tell that the problem doesn't occure in that build?

Comment: nope, I don't use Win10 , I'm still at Win8

Comment: As far as I can tell 14366 nor 14367 fixes the warning.

Comment: submit the issue via the Insider Feedback hub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warning is not existing anymore in build 14393.5